# Lucene Reverse Search

Tags: java, lucene

I have a list of keywords in my database. For ex: Java Program, Php program etc. I index these keywords using Lucene. When I search for a text longer than the keywords (indexed words), How will get a match? For ex: I am searching for "My Java Program is better than yours". I would expect a match because I have indexed a keywod "Java Program"? How to do this efficiently using Lucene? If not Lucene what else can I use for this kind of a job?

Please note, I don't want to match on independent keywords "java" and "program". I want a match on "Java Program" (as one keyword just as I indexed).

Thank you.

Comment: You could have a look at [MemoryIndex](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/api/contrib-memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html)

Comment: Why not use a phrase search?

Answer (score 2):

If you have indexed your keywords with a StandardAnalyzer, the you could query them quite effectively with a query string like this

```
My Java Program is better than yours.
```

Which, unless quoted or something like that, effectively interprets to 7 queries (less after removing stopwords), So it will match when looking for "java" and when looking for "program".

Comment: Sorry. I don't want to match "Java" and "Program" independently. I want to match on the exact keyword I indexed which is "Java Program". Thanks.

Comment: If you have the default sorting (relevancy) then your doc that is indexed with "Java Program" will score higher than, for example, one that just has "Java". Exact match will be tricker.

Comment: I am looking for an Yes or No. If I pick the top match, how will be able to cross check if its match on entire "java program" vs. "java" (or) "program"? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a [ShingleAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/shingle/ShingleAnalyzerWrapper.html) to split the query into varying length phrase queries.  That should ensure ordered matches have higher score.  You could also analyze your keywords with KeywordAnalyzer, if getting a low-scoring match on "Program Java" or just "Java" would cause the earth to be rent asunder.

Comment: Thank you. I used Keyword Analyzer while indexing. While searching I used ShingleAnalyzerWrapper(Analyzer defaultAnalyzer). It didn't find any matches. If I use the StandardAnalyzer for indexing and ShingleAnalyzer for searching, it finds it even if just "java" is in the search string. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: I would guess you need to normalize your keywords.  Putting the queries through the standard analyzer will run it through StandardFilter, LowercaseFilter, and StopFilter.  I would say you, at the very least, should lowercase your keywords first.